# How to improve the resolution of low cost GPS dongle?

Tags: gps

I recently bought a BU-353 G-STAR IV GPS receiver (common low cost GPS receiver in market). The update frequency according to the data sheet is 1 Hz. I set a baud rate of 4800 first and then 9600. But the map shows new position only after walking for 15 to 20 meters. Is this the norm? Is this because my GPS receiver's accuracy is 15 to 20 meters? Can I do any thing to obtain the current GPS location every second? i.e Can I update the resolution of the GPS dongle?

I am wondering why even the GPS in my smart phone seems to be at a higher resolution! The map shows continuous waypoints.

Answer (score 2):

I remember an old HTC phone I owned that used the same brand chipset (SiRF). Like yours, it would update its location only after moving a certain distance. I had to use a utility to modify some value from 'car' to 'pedestrian' to have it update more frequently.

Unfortunately, I cannot remember the name of the software, it may have been [SirfTech](http://w5.nuinternet.com/s660100031/SirfTech.htm), but that site seems to be down. Maybe you can find an alternative [here](http://www.maps-gps-info.com/fgpfw.html).

Comment: I couldn't find the SiRFTech software. I got this software called SiRFDemo https://www.falcom.de/support/software-tools/sirf/ . But unable to find how to change the mode. Please let me know if this was the name of the utility you used.

Comment: That doesn't ring a bell.